# CSS, With <input> how can I move the position where you type

Tags: css

So I found this code online for padding for the placeholder... But when I type, the padding is not there.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

[What I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx6Pl.jpg)

I drew a blue line on the provided photo to maybe explain what I mean.
I would like it to start type at the blue line position.

Comment: Sure, you set padding just for placeholder, not for _normal_ text (for whole input).

Comment: So this might be a stupid question.. but what? Do you just remove the -placeholder ?

Comment: No. Please read carefully what I wrote. Note: nothing like `::-webkit-input` doesn't exist.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to say. so mean ::-webkit-input-text { }  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try something like this :

```
.my_input {
    padding-left : 20px
}
```

my input being the class of your input (or ID or whatever)

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as the solution to close the post

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the padding in input instead of just placeholder.

```
input[type=text]
{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```